# How to rescue an Instance boot disk?

Tags: google-compute-engine, glibc

I know the request sounds specials, but I broke a glibc file while trying to upgrade it for my application.

I didn’t paid for backups. And I’m not paying for a second instance outside cloud shell. **This is for personal usage not professional type so It’s not related to ServerFault** (which is why creating a new one and deleting the current is not a solution).

I can roll back the upgrade: the previous files are already on the disk so what’s required is to perform a simple file copy on xfs. However, when I try to attach the disk elsewhere it does say that it’s in use by the instance even if it’s powered off.

Comment: As an alternative, is there a way to boot from an iso or even use the embedded initrd?

Comment: 1)To use a disk on a different instance, you must first detach it. 2) Google does not offer a feature to boot from ISO. 3) I am not sure what you mean by "embedded initrd". 4) Detach command: `gcloud compute instances detach-disk NAME --disk=DISK --zone=ZONE` 5) In this article I show the recovery commands for a different problem, but this article will help you with the steps. https://www.jhanley.com/google-cloud-recovering-from-ufw-lockout/

Comment: @JohnHanley I mean the initrd used to boot the system. For disk detach the system complains the machine needs at least 1 boot disk. Also how to attach to the cloud shell?

Comment: 1) Disk detach: did you read my article? 2) You cannot attach a disk to Cloud Shell. Cloud Shell is a container and not a Compute Engine instance. You will need to launch another instance, or use the startup command method in my article.

Comment: use the [Serial Console](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/interacting-with-serial-console).

Comment: @MartinZeitler I’m afraid that if no program can load glibc, then that no program can run on the serial console and that the only thing the system does is performing a kernel panic when attempting to start systemd.

Comment: @JohnHanley which will cost more money.

Comment: @MartinZeitler however, if you know how to use console for passing `root=/dev/ram0` kernel parameter which would allow to use the initrd for fixing the glibc, please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way for me to fix an issue like yours would be to [detach](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/instances/detach-disk) the disk from the current VM instance and [re-attach](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/instances/attach-disk) the disk to another VM instance as suggested by [John Hanley](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8016720/john-hanley).

I understand the cost may be factor but F1-Micro for 1-2 hours is [not so expansive](https://cloud.google.com/products/calculator/#id=fae329a3-df30-46f3-a388-979b692f9110).